# Registry Value for Notification Status in Windows 10

Tags: windows, notifications, registry, settings, key-value

I want to find the value in the registry that changes when I change the setting for notifications in Windows 10.[Picture how I deactivated the notifications.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNeji.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). It is capable of tracking Windows Registry changes. See https://superuser.com/q/317877/146834

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately there are several entries under the path I found which are being changed. Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\QuietHours\AlwaysAllowedApps